# How to get customize date format in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, string, datetime

I have a column named timee and data type is timestamp and the default value is current_timestamp.

My table looks like

```
id    title    timee
1     Abc      2020-10-31 00:31:47
2     Def      2020-10-31 00:35:50
```

I want to fetch data like

```
id    title    timee
1     Abc      31-10-2020
2     Def      31-10-2020
```

I tried `select id,title,time from tableName` but it's giving me the whole time but i don't know how to select just date and with dd-mm-yyyy format

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `date_format()`:

```
select id, title, date_format(timee, '%d-%m-%Y') timee
from mytable
```